# How to implement IConvertible

Tags: c#

I have some test code to check if 2 sides are equal.

```
public void GetCompanies_WithCorrectCompanyRequest_ReturnCompanyDtos()
    {
        // Arrange
        var companyRequset = new CompanyRequest();

        // Act
        var companyDtos = _datlinqServiceMock.GetCompanies(companyRequset);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(companyDtos != null && companyDtos.Any());
        Assert.AreEqual(DatlinqServiceMock.CompanyName, companyDtos.FirstOrDefault().Name);
    }
```

That calls this.

```
public class DatlinqServiceMock: DatlinqService
    {
        public static string CompanyName = "Company_Test";

        public override T GetApi<Q,T>(string apiMethod, Q request)
        {
            var companyList = new List<Company>()
            {
                new Company(){ Name = CompanyName}
            };

            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(companyList, typeof(T));
        }
    }
```

GetCompanies:

```
public List<Company> GetCompanies(CompanyRequest request)
        {
            if (request == null)
            {
                return new List<Company>();
            }
            var searchCompany = new SearchCompanyRequest();
            searchCompany.Query = request.Name;
            searchCompany.DatlinqKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Datlinq_Key"];
            var searchCompanyResponse = GetApi<SearchCompanyRequest,SearchCompanyResponse>(DatlinqApiMethod.SearchCompany, searchCompany);
            
            var companies = searchCompanyResponse.Result
               .Select(c => new Company { Id = c.Id, Name = c.Name })
               .ToList();
            return companies;
        }
```

GetApi:

```
public virtual T GetApi<Q,T>(string apiMethod, Q request)
    {
        var result = default(T);

        try
        {
            var url = String.Format("{0}{1}", _apiUrl, apiMethod);

            if (request != null)
            {
                url = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(url, request.ToDictionary());
            }

            var apiResponse = _httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
            if (apiResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string apiResponseString = apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiResponseString))
                {
                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(apiResponseString);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // do something
        }

        return result;
    }
```

And I get an error when I execute the first test

```
Message: 
Test method Lavazza.ContractTool.Datlinq.Tests.Services.DatlinqServiceTests.GetCompanies_WithCorrectCompanyRequest_ReturnCompanyDtos threw exception: 
System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.

  Stack Trace: 
Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType)
DatlinqServiceMock.GetApi[Q,T](String apiMethod, Q request) line 79
DatlinqService.GetCompanies(CompanyRequest request) line 23
DatlinqServiceTests.GetCompanies_WithCorrectCompanyRequest_ReturnCompanyDtos() line 32
```

I hope this is enough code to know what the problem/solution is if not let me know what you need.

To answer some question asked below.
Dai: I am trying to find what this is and why I need it because it came up in the error but the microsoft docs don't make it clear for me.

Jeroen: It is kind of a legacy project so I can't/won't add extra dependencies.

Comment: Why are you implementing `IConvertible`?

Comment: `(T)Convert.ChangeType(companyList, typeof(T));` <-- This does not do what you think it does.

Comment: How are you calling `GetApi`? We can only see a call to `GetCompanies` which is not shown

Comment: BTW you have here an [XYProblem](http://https://xyproblem.info/) - you're asking how to do "X" but really what you need to know is "Y".

Comment: Consider using libraries like Moq and NSubstitute for non-trivial mocks you generate on the fly; `Convert.ChangeType` isn't going to do that for you. Also consider more advanced assertion libraries like FluentAssertions which make it easier to check if objects are "equivalent" despite not having the same type, and whether collections of objects are structurally equivalent, all things that `Assert` is poorly equipped to do.

Comment: @Jamiec I guess that might be true do you know how I might better formulate this so other can understand better? 

I also added GetCompanies and GetApi

Answer (score 0):

The "issue" here is that your `GetApi` method is designed to return a sort of generic response - in this specific case `SearchCompanyResponse` - but you're trying to override it to return a `List<Company>` which is wrong because that is what your `GetCompanies` method does (ie turn a `SearchCompanyResponse` to a `List<Company>`).

Suffice it to say this has nothing to do with implementing `IConvertable`.

What you would be better off doing is serializing a `SearchCommpanyResponse` that you wish to use for testing to a file, and using that file-based response for your testing.

That way your overridden "Mock" would be

```
public override T GetApi<Q,T>(string apiMethod, Q request)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(File.ReadAllText("mytestfile.json"));
}
```